# Step into boost .ipp files using xcode 4.4.1 debugger

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, boost-asio

Is there any way to put breakpoints in .ipp implementation files provided with boost library?

With Visual studio, I was able to do so but xcode (4.4.1) do not identify .ipp files as code files.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This is not a working solution, but I hope somebody can continue from here.

As mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/263311/on-os-x-how-do-you-change-a-files-kind), file type associations of OSX are stored in `plist` files, so I wrote a short shell script that searches for the string `hpp` in all `plists` under a given directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

find $1 -iname "*.plist" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
  if plutil -convert xml1 "$file" -r -o - | grep -q "<string>hpp</string>"
  then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Calling the above script with `sh find_hpp.sh /Applications/Xcode.app` finds `Contents/Info.plist`, as expected. Note that this file cannot be edited directly with Xcode, since it is locked while Xcode is running, but you can quit Xcode, convert the binary plist file to xml via `plutil -convert xml1 Info.plist -o Info.xml`, edit the xml and convert it back with `plutil -convert binary1 Info.xml -o Info.plist`.

I just searched for `hpp` in the xml file and added `ipp` as an additional file type (it occurred twice):

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
                <string>hh</string>
                <string>hp</string>
                <string>hpp</string>
                <string>hxx</string>
                <string>h++</string>
                <string>ipp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>c-header_Icon</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>C++ Header Source</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
        <true/>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
                <string>public.c-plus-plus-header</string>
        </array>
</dict>
```

After converting the edited xml file back to binary, to force Launch Services to re-read the plist, I touched the app bundle:

```
touch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

I logged off and logged back on, but: nothing. Still not syntax highlighting in Xcode and not file association of `.ipp` files in Finder. I even restarted the system, moved the Xcode app bundle to my desktop and back. Still nothing. I hope that someone else can pick up from here.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`
2. Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> find `.cpp` and add near `.ipp` extension
3. Reboot